# Pasting from Snipping Tool into IE

Tags: image, internet-explorer, copy-paste

Alright StackOverflow, I've got a weird one today. I am working on adding pasting of images to a website. It works for Firefox and Chrome but fails for IE. When I turn on the debugger it gives an error on:

```
var items = event.clipboardData.items;
```

saying that `event.clipboardData.items` is undefined. What is the way to do this in IE?

Here is the code which actually comes from the WebKit layout tests:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function paste(event){
        var items = event.clipboardData.items;
        console.log(items.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
            if (items[i].kind == 'file' && items[i].type == 'image/png') {
                var blob = items[i].getAsFile();
                var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                document.getElementById('dest').src = url;
            }
        }
    }
    window.onload = function (e) { 
        document.body.onpaste = paste;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body contenteditable="true">
<img id="dest">
</body>
</html>
```

The specific workflow I'm trying to allow is for a user to use the Snipping Tool to take a snapshot and to then paste that image into IE. Normally I would tell the user to use Chrome or Firefox but this is for work and we are restricted to IE. Thanks for the help!

My testing Environment:
Windows 8 64bit
IE 10

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old issue, but copying an image from snipping tool to IE10 is simply not possible. The functionality is added in Edge. IE10 does not have the tools to paste images from clipboard.